# Convergence of $x_n=f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right), n\geq 1$

Tags: derivatives, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem to solve:

Let $f:]0,1[ \rightarrow R$ be a differentiable function over $]0,1[$, with $|f'(x)|\leq 1, \forall x \in ]0,1[$.

(a) Show that the sequence $x_n=f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right), n\geq 1$, is convergent.

(b) Does the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ exist?

I think the Mean Value Theorem can be useful but I cannot see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the MVT, if $m > n$, then there exists a point $\xi \in (1/m,1/n) \subset (0,1)$ such that

$$|f(1/m) - f(1/n)| = |f'(\xi)||1/m - 1/n| \leqslant \frac{|m-n|}{mn} = \frac1{n}(1 - n/m) < \frac1{n}.$$

For all $m > n> 1/\epsilon,$ we have

$$|f(1/m) - f(1/n)|  < \epsilon.$$

Therefore $f(1/n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, and, hence, convergent.

For part (b), there exists for all $x,y \in (0,1)$ a point $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\xi)||x-y| \leqslant |x-y|.$$

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(1/n) = L$ exists, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that both $1/N < \epsilon/2$ and $|f(1/N) - L| < \epsilon/2.$

Hence,

$$|f(x) - L| \leqslant |f(1/N) - L| + |f(x) - f(1/N)|  \leqslant \epsilon/2  +  |x - 1/N|.$$

If $0 < x < 1/N,$ then $|x - 1/N| < 1/N < \epsilon/2$ and

$$|f(x) - L| < \epsilon. $$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(1/n) = L.$$

Comment: How come the power series method doesn't apply to this question?

Comment: @K. Gibson: The series $\sum 1/n^p$ with $0 < p < 1$ diverges but $1/n^p$ still converges to $0$.  Nevertheless I don't think it has anything  to do with this problem.

Comment: thanks! I'll try to get the solution for (b)

Comment: Sorry -- I just added it. Don't look and give it a try -- check back if you have trouble.

Comment: No problem! I was trying using the result from (a) ;-)