# Whats the difference between a series and sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

I was looking at a question earlier that involved sequences and found out that the sequence converged to 0 but the series diverged to infinity. How is that possible? for example the sequence was $a_n$ $=$ $\frac{1}{x_n}$ 
The question was here: [Convergence of $x_n=f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right), n\geq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784597/convergence-of-x-n-f-left-frac1n-right-n-geq-1/1784609#1784609)

Comment: I do not understand. The referenced question did not mention series. Do you mean how can you have $\sum a_n=\infty$ even though $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$? If so, the answer is yes, eg $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 7):

A sequence is an infinite list of numbers:
$$a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$$
while a series is the formal expression you get when you insert "plus" symbols:
$$a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots$$
Loosely stated, the sequence converges iff the numbers in the list approaches some limit number $a$. And the series converges iff some number $s$ can be said to be the *sum* of the series.

If the series converges to some sum $s$, it is not hard to show that the corresponding sequence converges to $a=0$. However, the converse is not true; if the sequence converges to $a=0$, the series obtained by inserting plusses may not converge. In a sense this happens when the terms $a_n$ tend to zero *too slowly*.

Answer (score 6):

A series *is* in some sense a type of sequence. However, it is a sequence of **partial sums.**

For example, if we take some sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, then we can in turn retrieve a series from this sequence by considering the following partial sums:

$S_N=a_1+...+a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n$

Then if we consider the following sequence: $\{S_N\}_{n \geq 1}$ We have actually defined a series!

$S_1=a_1$

$S_2=a_1+a_2$

and so on.

Thus, the difference is the following:

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ defined by $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

It is intuitively clear (and if not, use the Archimedean property) that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$.

Now, we can consider the *sequence of partial sums:*

Let $\{S_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be defined by $S_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{n}$

Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

Which is called the **harmonic series**, and it diverges.

We can show this by either the integral test, or just note:

$\begin{align} &1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+...\\
>&1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+...\\
=&1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+...
\end{align}$

Which very clearly diverges.

As an aside, it should be very clear that $\{S_n\}$ will not converge at all if $\{a_n\}$ does not, but the converse is not true.

If you want an example where they both converge, just take $\{a_n\}$ to be defined by $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$. Then you can consider the sequence of partial sums for $a_n$ (and hence, define a series.)

Then $\{a_n\} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Yet we also have that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1/2}{1-1/2}=1$$

To see a derivation of the penultimate equality, you can look further into what are called [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html)

Answer (score 4):

> An essential difference is that
>
> - a sequence has  *one* specific  meaning and
> - a series has *two  different* specific meanings.

For convenience only we look at real-valued sequences and series.

> **Sequences:** A *sequence* of real numbers 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(a_n\right)_{n\geq 0}=(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots)
> \end{align*}
>
> is a *function* from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The  index  set  $\mathbb{N}$ is the  domain of the function and    the real   numbers $\mathbb{R}$  is   the codomain.

Now let's have a look at series. We have to clearly state the meaning(s) of the symbol
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\tag{1}
  \end{align*}
with $a_n$ being real numbers.

> **Series (as sequences):** Infinite series are sequences of partial sums
>
> When looking at a sequence $(a_0,a_{1},a_{2},\ldots)=(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$
>   we consider
>   \begin{align*}
>   (a_0,a_{0}+a_{1},a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2},\ldots) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n\right)_{N\geq 0}
>   \end{align*}
>   and *define* the infinite series (1) as the *sequence of partial sums*
>   \begin{align*}
>     \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n:= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n\right)_{N\geq 0}\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}

So, the LHS of (2) is just a new and *very convenient* representation for the sequence of partial sums
\begin{align*}
  \left(s_N\right)_{N\geq 0}, \qquad s_N=\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n\tag{3}
  \end{align*}

The symbol $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ has also a second meaning, namely

> **Series (as values):** Infinite series are the *limits* of the sequences of partial sums
>
> An infinite series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ is said to be *convergent, definitely divergent or indefinitely divergent* according as the sequence of its partial sums shows the behaviour indicated by those names.
>
> If, in the case of convergence, the sequence of partial sums, $s_N\rightarrow s$, then we say that $s$ is the *value* or the *sum* of the *convergent infinite series* and we write for brevity
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n:=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}s_N=s
>   \end{align*}
>   so that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ denotes not only the sequence $(s_N)_{N\geq 0}$ but also the limit $s$, provided this limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

A *sequence* of real numbers is a delineation; more specifically, it is a function from the positive integers into $\mathbb{R}$; e.g., $\lbrace a_{n} \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty} = a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots $, where the $a_{i}$ are real numbers.

A *series* is a summation of a particular sequence.